# Adding an active merchant offsite payment gateway to spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, activemerchant

I need to add the active merchant offsite payment gateway "Direct-Ebanking" / Sofortüberweisung.de to my Spree Commerce Project. However there seems to be close to NO documentation on how to do this. The best I could find is a link pointing to the list of supported gateways in the active_merchant read me on github. But how exactly do Spree and Active Merchant work together? is there any short tutorial or hint on how to implement an active_Merchant supported offsite gateway (because the idea here is, to support more than credit card payments)?

Any help is highly appreciated..

Thanks heaps.

Max

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you can check out that: https://github.com/fschwahn/spree_payment_network However, the gem is outdated.

Spree is supporting activemerchant, which helps you to integrate any new payment methods to spree. A good example is the 'better_spree_paypal_express' gem

Also you may look at the activemerchant directebanking integration test file as a guide to create an extension for spree: https://github.com/Shopify/offsite_payments/blob/master/test/unit/integrations/directebanking/directebanking_helper_test.rb

Comment: I am using offsite_payments gem which is extracted out of ActiveMerchant gem. With ActiveMerchant 2.0, offsite_payments gem will not be included together with activemerchant and thus makes me think twice on moving to spree.